# Differential Form and Pullback of Composition of Smooth Functions (Proof Verification)

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, tensors

Let $f: \mathbb{R^3} \to \mathbb{R^2}$ be $C^\infty$ and let $g: \mathbb{R^2} \to \mathbb{R^3}$ be $C^\infty$. Let $h=g \circ f$ and denote the pullback of $h$ by $h^\ast$.Let $\omega$ be a smooth 2-form on $\mathbb{R^3}$. Prove that $$d(h^\ast \omega)=0.$$

**My proof**

\begin{align*}
d(h^\ast \omega)
& = h^\ast (d\omega) \\
& = (g\circ f)^\ast (d\omega) \\
& = f^\ast (g^\ast (d\omega)) \\
& = f^\ast (d(g^\ast \omega)) \\
\end{align*}

Denote the set of all k-forms on an open set $A\in \mathbb{R^n}$ by $\Omega^k (A)$. Then we have that

\begin{align*}
\omega\in \Omega^2 (\mathbb{R^3})
& \implies g^\ast \omega\in \Omega^2 (\mathbb{R^2}) \\
& \implies d(g^\ast \omega)\in \Omega^3 (\mathbb{R^2}) \\
& \implies d(g^\ast \omega)=0 \\
& \implies d(h^\ast \omega)=0 \\
\end{align*}

The second last step holds because on a 2-dimensional space, any alternating 3-tensor (which is uniquely determined by its values on 3-tuples of basis elements, in which there will always be repetitions) is identically zero.

I'm not quite sure if my proof is correct, since it almost has nothing to do with the map $f$. Can anyone check whether what I've done is logically flawed? All suggestions are appreciated!